# 'EnableViewState = false' of an asp.net DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

If an asp.net DropDownList's is set to EnableViewState=false, DropDownList.SelectedItem returns null.

Then what technique can I use to get the SelectedItem of that DropDownList while keeping that EnableViewState=false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Request.Form[yourDropDownList.UniqueID]
```

UniqueID returns "ctl00$ContentMain$ddlCountry" where as
ClientID returns "ctl00_ContentMain_ddlCountry"

The UniqueID is inserted to the name of the HTML form which is used in the postback form name.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.Request.Form[this.List.ClientID];
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the problem is that you're data-binding the drop down list manually in the code behind file. It might help to move your data binding from `Page_Load()` to `Page_Init()`.

But in my opinion a better solution would be to use an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) to fill in the values of your DropDownList. That way you're sure that you're loading in the values a the correct time in the page life cycle.

Comment: Jan, I have a similar situation and for some reason my RadComboBox is losing its value on postback. I am using an ObjectDataSource and always thought it takes care of binding at the right point during the page life cycle, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, Jacques, I can't help you with that one. It would make a quick test with a regular DropDownList. If this works, then the problem could be inside the control. Otherwise try asking here on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string selectedValue = Request.Form["MyDropDownList"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution using VS2010.
1.  Set EnableViewState to false.
2.  Bind the dropdownlistbox to a sqldataadapter.

Before:
After setting EnableViewState to false, I had to reload the listbox on every postback.  This worked.  However the very first time a value was slected from the list, the SelectedIndexChanged event fired, but the selectecitem.Value did not change (it remained at "0").  The second time a value was slected from the list, the selectecitem.Value was correct.